# Opencv: AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'dnn'

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am just starting with computer vision. While running [code](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/02/26/face-detection-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/) I got the following error.

[INFO] loading model...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect_faces_video.py", line 24, in 
    net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'dnn'

I believe that the error is because my opencv version is 3.1.0 and for this tutorial to work I need at least the 3.3.0 version.

So the better question would be, How can I upgrade my opencv to 3.3.0 from 3.1.0. Do I need to delete the 3.1.0 version first?

I have installed my opencv in a virtual environment.

Thanks

Comment: How did you install it in the first place? just....do that again with the new version?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I got it to work by making another virtual environment. Then Installing the latest version of opencv.

`$ mkvirtualenv cv`

`$ sudo pip3 install opencv-contrib-python`

Answer (score 3):

Similar to other answers, I've had multiple successes (for reasons I'm not sure of) by just uninstalling opencv and re-installing in the exact **same environment** and **same opencv** version:

```py
pip3 uninstall opencv-python-headless
pip3 install opencv-python-headless
```

Comment: In a brand new `venv` the order seems to make a different.  I started multiple times installing only hand full of libraries.  I found that installing `opencv` last, or uninstalling it and reinstalling it last fixes it every time.  weird.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to open an new venv.

```
conda create --name myEnv python=3.9
conda activate myEnv
```

Then install the library you need. This works for me.