# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'dnn'

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, yolov4

I am trying to detect objects in a picture. I am using my trained weights and configuration file. The code runs completely fine on my laptop but it shows
**AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'dnn'**
when I run it on my Raspberry Pi 4B. I have python 3.7 and Open CV 4.5.1
I am unable to solve this.
what should I do.

Comment: Does this help you? https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib, https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17582, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575800/opencv-attributeerror-module-cv2-has-no-attribute-dnn? There seems to be additional modules you have to install directly.

Comment: you have a build with the DNN module disabled. the DNN module is not contrib, it's part of the main code base. it can be disabled for many reasons. build OpenCV yourself to have full control.

Comment: That's strange, I was able to use `cv2.dnn`. My OpenCV version is also `4.5.1`. and I installed it using the command `pip install opencv-python`. What command did you use to install it, are you using a virtualenv or installing globally?