# cv2.dnn issue with using SDD in deepface.analyze(): no attribute 'readNetFromCaffe'

Tags: python, opencv, caffe, deepface

I have installed opencv-python version 4.9.0.80 and [deepface](https://github.com/serengil/deepface) version 0.0.81. and it seems to cause an issue when I try to run DeepFace.analyze() with SSD detector backend:

`DeepFace.analyze('Img.jpg', ['race'], detector_backend = 'ssd', enforce_detection= False, silent = False)`

```
File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/deepface/detectors/SsdWrapper.py:46, in build_model()
     42     output = home + "/.deepface/weights/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
     44     gdown.download(url, output, quiet=False)
---> 46 face_detector = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(
     47     home + "/.deepface/weights/deploy.prototxt",
     48     home + "/.deepface/weights/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel",
     49 )
     51 eye_detector = OpenCvWrapper.build_cascade("haarcascade_eye")
     53 detector = {}

AttributeError: module 'cv2.dnn' has no attribute 'readNetFromCaffe'
```

Any help solving this issue would be greatly appreciated. I'm running this on python jupyter via anaconda3-notebook.

UPDATE (1/18/2024)

As per @Ro.oT and @johncasey, I've installed opencv-contrib, but it has not solved the issue:

```
pip3 list | grep opencv 
opencv-contrib-python        4.9.0.80
opencv-python                4.9.0.80
```

Comment: Do you have `opencv-contrib` installed? If not, then install via: `pip install opencv-contrib-python` and then run the same code again.

Comment: @Ro.oT `dnn` module is a core module, not a contrib module. installing the +contrib package will not solve this. in fact, it will just break your installation. never install different opencv packages in the same python/environment. all opencv packages contain the core modules but if you install `opencv-python` and `opencv-contrib-python` at the same time, that'll break everything.

Comment: @dai `pip3 list | grep opencv` please, or whatever anaconda requires. [edit] your question to add the results.

Comment: @Christoph, I see. I saw an outdated [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52575800/opencv-attributeerror-module-cv2-has-no-attribute-dnn) related to `dnn` where the accepted solution was to install contrib module. Moments later, I actually found your comment regarding this in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66934701/attributeerror-module-cv2-has-no-attribute-dnn#comment118319143_66934701). Thank you for the useful information.

Comment: opencv-contrib-python is not a must dependency in deepface. in other words, when you install deepface, it is installing its dependecies but opencv-contrib-python is not one of them. the reason, why this modulu is excluded from dependencies is to decrease the package size. [here](https://github.com/serengil/deepface/blob/master/requirements_additional.txt), you can find the optional dependencies of deepface. so, installing opencv-contrib-python should sort this. on the other hand, in the library side, you should see a meaningful error.

Comment: would you please run this command in a cell of jupyter notebook please: `!pip install opencv-contrib-python`. I suspect jupyter is using a different environment. That is why, running pip install in terminal may install it in a different environment. Running this command in notebook's cell will guarantee to install that package in the same environment.